# Automatically resize font in a text box

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, text, font, dynamic-text

I'm using dynamic text for owner names in my layout.  Problem is some are two words and some are a lot more.

When using a text box if the font is to big it just drops the extra.

Is there an easy way to simply have the font automatically resize to fit in the text box?  Something like the legend being able to resize/shrink to fit?

Comment: What GIS Software are you using?  Also I see that although you've been a user here for a while you haven't yet taken the [tour] which outlines our Question and Answer format

Comment: ArcGIS 10.2, and I'll look into that tour.

Comment: Can you provide any screen shots displaying the issue you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing I can think of is using the [Adding text that flows within a graphic](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s800000004000000).

This allows you to:

> You can add text that flows within a graphic to your map annotation or graphic text by using the Polygon Text, Rectangle Text, and Circle Text tools on the Draw toolbar.
>
> Choose either Polygon Text Polygon Text [image], Rectangle Text Rectangle Text [image], or Circle Text Circle Text [image].

You can create your custom text box

[image]

Your text will conform to that text box shape

[image]

So, depending on the shape you would choose that option from the Draw Toolbar.

Comment: I was using a Rectangle Text Box hoping that would do it.  The problem was it wouldn't resize the font to fit it all in there.  It just drops whatever doesn't fit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to dynamically resize the font. Perhaps a workaround would be to calculate a new field which will contain suitable abbreviations of the owner names (depending on the data you could possibly take just the last word, or first and last, whatever is going to suit your purpose), and use that in your dynamic text.